# How to update $PATH of guest vm using vagrant

Tags: bash, vagrant, devops, minishift

I'm trying to export the $PATH of a guest vm to be able to use the minishift command. This is what I have in the Vagrantfile, but is not working, any hint?

```
mvm.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "echo 'export PATH=$PATH:~/minishift-1.7.0-linux-amd64' >>~/.bashrc"
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? Do you want to run Minishift within a Vagrant virtual machine? That won't work since Minsihfit is intended to run on your local machine. In fact it will spin off it's own VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the next:

```
mvm.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/home/vagrant/minishift-1.7.0-linux-amd64' >>/home/vagrant/.bashrc"
```

For some reason Vagrant is not interpreting correctly "~/"